# Deleting duplicates in a linked list

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I can't see my error. I'm using a list where the insert method puts every new element added in order. I'm trying not to use hashtables for this case. 
I wrote out a control flow graph, wrote it on paper, and it seems to make sense in those mediums but i'm not able to get the results i'm looking for. 
My list: 0,1,1,1,2,4,5,7
It is the exact same after I run it through this method:

```
public class List {

int value;
List next;

List(int value, List next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

}
public void deleteDuplicates() {
    List marker = head;
    List pointer = marker;

    while(marker != null && marker.next != null){
        while(pointer.next != null){
            if(marker.value == pointer.next.value){
                pointer.next = pointer.next.next;
            }
            else{
                pointer = pointer.next;
            }
        }
        marker = marker.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `next` and `value` looks weird. Have you made your own list class? I am pretty sure there are no fields in `LinkedList` with those names.

Comment: Yeah, it's for learning how it actually works. As opposed to using the classes java provides, i was using my own list. Value is the element in the list and next is the reference pointer.

Comment: I think we need to see your class, then. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: What type is `List.value`? If it's not a primitive `==` won't work, you'll need to use `value.equals()`

Comment: ... and override equals if it is custom class as well.

Comment: Well, I instantiate the List class. Using some reference name such as "foo" so I can just say "if (foo.value < foo.next.value)" or something. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting the `pointer` variable after the end of the inner loop: after `marker = marker.next;` you should add `pointer = marker;`

Also `Node` seems a better name rather than `List`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are having two pointers (`marker` and `pointer`) but not making any use of the second pointer (`pointer`). If you are coming across same value you are incrementing the pointer but eventually throwing away `pointer` without making any use of it.

A more succinct way to eliminate duplicates would be as follows -

```
List marker=head;
    List pointer;

    while(marker != null && marker.next != null){
        pointer = marker.next;
        while(pointer != null && marker.value == pointer.value){ //Skip nodes which have same value
                pointer = pointer.next;
        }
        marker.next = pointer;
        marker = marker.next;
    }
```